# How to get active/focused notebook's full path in JupyterLab's UI extension?

Tags: javascript, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I am developing a custom JupyterLab extension and I need to get active/focused notebook's full path on a button click.
I already have the button and the click registered. I wanted to get the path from the `defaultFileBrowser.listing.selection` but selection doesn't have the focused notebooks url when the lab screen is split.

Comment: Does [this answer to 'How to retrieve the notebook directory in developing jupyterlab extension?'](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-retrieve-the-notebook-directory-in-developing-jupyterlab-extension/21311/4?u=fomightez) cover getting that?

Comment: Why do you want to use file browser for this task? You can get the path of the active notebook from (a) the `INotebookTracker` widget or (b) if your button is in the notebook toolbar from the notebook directly.